# Detect connection abort on a socket opened by fsockopen()

Tags: php, sockets, tcp

I am using `fsockopen()` to send data via TCP to a remote host:

```
$s = fsockopen($host, $port);
fwrite($s, $data);
fclose($s);
```

How can I detect afterwards if the connection was closed (with a FIN) or aborted (with a RST) by the remote host?

Comment: Annoyingly, you can't (AFAIK). You can detect whether the socket has been closed *or* aborted before your call `fclose()` with `feof()`, but you can't determine which it is. Although I do wonder how useful this information would be, after all a dead socket is a dead socket, no matter what happened to it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation [socket_last_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-last-error.php) and [socket_send()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-send.php) can be helpful for you:

```
socket_send() returns the number of bytes sent, or FALSE on error. 
socket_last_error() returns the last error on the socket
```

I believe, that PHP is able to detect if the connection was closed, however not sure about this.